# Execute function when leaving page or

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to write a function that shows if a user is logged in or not. The function should make a change in the database when a user leaves the site , and this is my current code:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
$.ajax({
        url: "change_to_logged_out.php",
        success: function(data){
            alert(data)
         }
      });
});
```

The code isn't executed when the user reloads the page, which is what I want, but is executed when someone closes the tab or the window, also good. But if the user just clicks on a link redirecting to another page on my site, the code is executed. How can I make so that the function ignores if the user clicks on a link to somewhere else on the site, but not if the user is redirected to a different site? Maybe there's a better way to make a function like this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What happens when a user has multiple tabs open on your site? You don't want to log a user out if he/she has multiple tabs and closes one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

External selector was taken from here: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/extending-jquerys-selector-capabilities/

```
$.expr[":"].external = function(el){
   if(!el.href) {return false;}
   return el.hostname && el.hostname !== window.location.hostname;
};
var clicked = 0;
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
!clicked && $.ajax({
        url: "change_to_logged_out.php",
        success: function(data){
            alert(data)
         }
      });
});
$(document).on('click', 'a:external', function(){clicked = 1;});
```

Comment: I assume that submitting internal form is also not the desired behavior to fire the event. Adding `$('form').submit(function() { submitted = 1; })` together with `!submitted && !clicked && $.ajax..` will secure also that case.